# jquery mobile individual page background

Tags: jquery-mobile

Adding an image to a jquery mobile page and unable to prevent it from repeating.  OK for mobile devices but when viewed on tablet or desktop it is not OK to repeat'  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css"/>
<script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="b"  style="background-
image:url(images/bkgrnd-7.jpg)">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>Page One</h1>
</div>

</div>
<div data-role="content">
 Content        
</div>

<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div>

<!--Additional pages and content with their own backgrounds...-->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
background:url(images/bkgrnd-7.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: I am so sorry for my ignorance but where would I place this code?  I tried it in place of the style="background-image:url(images/bkgrnd-7.jpg)" but it didn't work.

Comment: maybe you trying to put no-repeat to background-image? if so, it wouldn't work there, background should.

Comment: OK that got it so it doesn't repeat!!! Any ideas on how to center the image and keep it there regardless of screen size?  The buttons I have on the page remain centered on all screens (tablets, desktop etc) but the image is to the left on tablets and desktop now.  Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: Think I found it style="background:url(images/bkgrnd-7.jpg) no-repeat; background-position:center"   Seems to work

Comment: that will do it, one more thing to keep in mind - it will be centered horizontally and vertically, if you want it to be on top-center, you should use both: background:url(images/bkgrnd-7.jpg) no-repeat top center;

Answer (score 0):

You would add the CSS property `no-repeat` to the background image and make it dependent on the media rules property of CSS3.

```
@media screen /*Computer screen*/
@media handheld /*Mobile devices*/
```

but keep in mind that a tablet may be considered a mobile device or a regular screen.

so you can do something like this

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 800px)
@media handheld and (min-device-width: 480px)
```